# Visual Studio: Find project(s) that are no more in the solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

We are currently using TFS to manage our source code. The issue is that when we delete a project from the solution within visual studio, it doesn't delete them from the the disk and the source control don't remove them(all this is by design, I can understand why).

The thing is that we have a very big source base(active solution has more than 250 projects), and we frequently have to refactor some things to handle new features. Sometimes, people forgot to also delete the file on the disk and commit their removal.

So I would like to know if there is a way to find every C# projects under a specific repository, that are not referenced in the active solution in Visual Studio(or if it's by an external tool, to a specific sln).

Thank you very much

Comment: You can parse .sln to get all projects being included.

Comment: Well, I know I can do it myself with some c# code, but why reinvent the wheel. My guess that I'm not the first one with this issue

Comment: I thought it pretty easy job: listing all projects paths, parse all .sln by regex, excluding found projects. Of course, I also want to know if there an existing solution too.